# How to Set Root/Base URL for a VueJS Project

Tags: vuejs2, vue.js

I've deployed a `VueJS` project to a domain like `www.example.com`, however, I want to move it to a subfolder so that I can access it like `www.example.com/v1`

How can I set the base URL or root URL of a `VueJS` project?

Note: It's not about the base URL for `Vue-resource`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [option](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/options.html) `base` as `/v1/` to move all routes to have base as `/v1/`.

> The base URL of the app. For example, if the entire single page application is served under /app/, then base should use the value "/app/".

### Old

How about moving all your routes to [nested route](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/nested-routes.html), with parent route being `/v1`:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: 'v1', component: BaseView,
      children: [
        {
          // UserProfile will be rendered inside BaseView's <router-view>
          // when /v1/profile is matched
          path: 'profile',
          component: UserProfile
        },
        {
          // UserPosts will be rendered inside BaseView's <router-view>
          // when /v1/posts is matched
          path: 'posts',
          component: UserPosts
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Hmm. Don't know whether this is the best solution. No other easy way?

Comment: @GijoVarghese you can use `base` option in the route object, check my update.

Comment: But how can I set the base URL?

Comment: Ok, I've set the base url in router. But still after building, in the index.html file, the resource files doesn't start with /v1

Comment: Yes, it does not seems to work as I had expected it, not yet sure [why](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42664712/1610034).

Comment: Hmm looks weird!!! For now, I've created subdomains that solved the problem easily. Like v1.example.com