# How base option works in vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

As par [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/options.html) of base option:

> The base URL of the app. For example, if the entire single page application is served under /app/, then base should use the value "/app/".

But I have tried it like following, It does not seems to work:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  base: "/app/",
  routes
})
```

Demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xgrjzsup/1352/).

Answer (score 14):

The base has a default value of `'/'`. Drawing analogy from how it is used to route:

```
<router-link to="home">Home</router-link>
```

or

```
<router-link :to="{ path: '/abc'}" replace></router-link>
```

I just omitted the `/app` and it [works](http://jsfiddle.net/nhwva3jm/). The base doesn't need to be part of the `router-link`

**EDIT**

### Use of `base` in `vue-router`

*(For this test I had used `vue-cli` with the `webpack` template.)*

I had my router configurations like so:

```
export default new Router({
  base: '/app',
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'RangeInputDemo',
      component: ComponentDemo
    }
  ]
})
```

Adding base as `'/app'` made no difference to the routing that happened throughout the project, as if the base was still set to `'/'`.

---

I tried to change the url from the server side (the url at which the project is being served).

So in `dev-server.js` where :

```
var uri = 'http://localhost:' + port
```

controls the url of the app, I made a slight modification to:

```
var uri = 'http://localhost:' + port + '/app'
```

This caused the application to show:

[image]
[image]

Notice the `fullPath` being `'/'` in the vue console (second image).

Just for double checking, I changed the `base` to `'/'` again.

[image]

---

So, the `base` property of the `router` configuration is to set the base url as set by the server, if the server serves the application at a route other than `'/'` then the `base` can be used for having the application be run from the set url.

---

Since the question requires the routes being moved under `/app`, I think having `/app` as the parent route would be the solution in that case, if the server isn't supposed to change the route on which it serves.

Comment: But I want all the routes to move under /app/, as asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42664144/1610034).

Comment: In the fiddle I just saw that the routing won't happen, I think I need to try this once in some project to check, if it is not getting added in url. I hope that is the case? You are not having `/app/<route>` in the url?

Comment: I am not sure why it should not work in fiddle when nested routes also works.

Comment: I see same behaviour in a vue project. Adding the base route doesn't show up in the url, everything else works indifferent to the base route, as if it is still `'/'`. In fact if I manually add `/app` in the url no route works.

Comment: Also confused about what `base` actually means.. it's always relative to the path of the page I'm on from the server? (basically prefixes the path according to the router?)

Answer (score 12):

In the Vue Router 4, you set base path by history api:

```
 const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})
```

Then each path would be prefixed with process.env.BASE_URL

Comment: You can't imagine how mush time you saved me.  Mush be the accepted solution.  For those who what to get in production in sub-folder, don't forget to build with "base" option i.e.     "build": "vite build --base=/sub-path/",

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem, setting "base" didn't work - workaround is to update base url in router:

```
{ name: 'listings', path: baseUrl + '/listings',   component: PageListings}
```

and refer to routes by name:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'listings' }" exact>Listings</router-link>
```

Comment: Thank you. I lost several hours before I've stumbled on your answer.

Comment: @Milan I'd also recommend extracting route names under a dictionary, and import it at components, so instead of string literals, map would be used: `{ name: Routes.listings }`. Will help to avoid mistypes, plus autosuggest benefits.

Answer (score 0):

I created a redirect on the base path to another route.

```
 {
    name: "Default",
    path: '/',
    redirect: { name: 'OtherRouteName' }
 }
```

Reference:
https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html