# Vue3 to be called under "/app/some/" instead of "/" (during development)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

As far as I got it by default a vite application is located under ´http://localhost/index.html´.
But I want it call under ´http://localhost/app/some/index.html´ - during development.

I am updating a vue2 project to vue3. Back then the issue was configured in the `vue.config.js` as

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  publicPath: '/app/some/',
  ...
};
```

Now, the `vue.config.js` is not used anymore, but there is a `vite.config.ts` and I do not know how to address configuring the new path.
I also use **vue4-router** like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68210905/845117). But I do not know how to set or configure 'process.env.BASE_URL'. The old router under vue2 took a configuration like this:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  base: '/app/some',
  ..
});
```

The new router does not support the `base` property anymore.
Just replacing `process.env.BASE_URL` with hardcoded `/app/some/` does not work either. And it seems that there must be some kind of property being set instead of a hardcoded value.

As far as I read [here](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html) and [here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html) I still do not get the clue how to configure it. I am always missing an example part where these settings are applied in a greater context in order to understand where and in what file it is made. So far I figured it's all in the `vite.config.ts` but nothing worked for me so far.

Can anyone give me a hint on this?

This all yields to the **devlopment** phase. On production this application is packed into a Springboot-Jar file to be served as web content (https://www.codecentric.de/wissens-hub/blog/spring-boot-vuejs). But I did not reach the packing part yet...