# Base option in vue router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

This issue has been discussed several times ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42664712/how-base-option-works-in-vue-router) - [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42664112/how-to-set-root-base-url-for-a-vuejs-project/42664144#42664144)) but I still cannot get it to work. I'm transitioning our project to use vue in some parts. What I want to accomplish is:

- If url starts with `/v/`, look into vue router and match path.
- If url starts with anything other than `/v/`, ignore it (this view will be rendered by current framework from backend).

My router looks like:

```
const router = new Router({
    base: '/v/',
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes
});
```

Where routes are:

```
const routers = [
    ...
    {
        path: '/wholesale-catalogue/',
        name: 'wholesale-catalogue',
        component: () => import('./views/WholesaleCatalogue.vue')
    }
    ...
]
```

The second option I tried is nesting the children routes:

```
const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        { path: 'v', component: BaseView, children: routers }
    ]
});
```

The problem is that the router reroutes non `/v/` urls into `/v/` when clicked within the website, such as:

`ourwebsite.com/home/` -> has some links on it, such as `/about/`. When you click on `/about/` it actually goes to `ourwebsite.com/about/` for a few seconds but then the url changes to `/ourwebsite.com/v/about/`. This leads to some annoyances as when you refresh the website, this url doesn't exist (on our current backend framework) so it will not render.

Comment: Is the Vue router defined even for pages served from urls not starting with `/v` ? It seems to me like the backend should not inject Vue at all in pages not managed by Vue and yet you say the router "takes over" somehow.

Comment: @bernie the vue is injected into all pages to take advantage of vuex & localstorage but only shows content if it matches correct url.